# Wrong string id is used in Advanced Search Tips

Tags: bug, search, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As far as I can see the string "Answers" from the [Advanced Search Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) is used from the wrong transifex id:

> [image: Answers]

According to the current translation on ruSO I see the usage of pluralizable form ["Answers"](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11357) instead of the non-pluralizable ["Answers"](https://ru.traducir.win/string/4884):

> [image]