# Not all apples and tags are allowed to translate

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, localization

There is an exclude section on the bottom of the [search page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search). That section contains two untranslatable words: "apples" and "tag". At the same time these words are translated on the rest part of page:

> [image: apples tag]

Could these sentences please be added to the translation database for the sake of integrity?

Comment: I have a fix ready for review, should be able to ship it early next week.

Comment: New record for shortest time between Meta post and fix being developed?  Less than 20 minutes :-)

Comment: @RyanM Arrgh, beat my record for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356396/accepted-answer-icon-is-out-of-alignment-on-highly-scored-answers ;)

Comment: @RyanM It’s because bug’s critical level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks for fixing. Could you please take a look at another related [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323420/339911). It seems easy to fix.